# How to remove Google Drive folder after uninstalling Google Drive on MacOSX 13.5.1

Tags: macos, privacy, google-drive-for-desktop

I've uninstalled Google Drive from my company laptop running MacOSX 13.5.1 (by deleting the application from the Application folder using Finder, and I wanted to delete my Google Drive Data, which do not worked.

Deleting the Data folder using Finder do not work. (nothing happens)

I went to

```
cd /Users/user/Library/CloudStorage/
```

and tried to removed my GoogleDrive-email@domain.com with

```
rm -rf GoogleDrive-email@domain.com
or
sudo rm -rf GoogleDrive-email@domain.com
```

it removed most of the files excepted the following kind of files :

```
rm: cannot remove 'GoogleDrive-email@domain.com/Other computers/My MacBook Pro': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove 'GoogleDrive-email@domain.com/.shortcut-targets-by-id/<SOME GOOGLE FILE ID>': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove 'GoogleDrive-email@domain.com/.tmp/2XXX2/<Some Google File Name>.gsheet': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove 'GoogleDrive-email@domain.com/.file-revisions-by-id': Operation not permitted
```

So there's still sensitive information left from multiple accounts (not just email@domain.com), the other accounts were never synced to this computer.
Sensitive information like Google File ID, google file names, my Google Drive Account email.

```
file 'GoogleDrive-email@domain.com/.tmp/XXXX/<FILE NAME>.gsheet'
GoogleDrive-email@domain.com/.tmp/XXXX/<FILE NAME>.gsheet: JSON data

cat 'GoogleDrive-email@domain.com/.tmp/XXXX/<FILE NAME>.gsheet'
{"":"WARNING! DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE! ANY CHANGES MADE WILL BE LOST!","doc_id":"<GOOGLE FILE ID>","resource_key":"","email":"email@domain.com"}
```

I could move the folder to /tmp, but still couldn't delete it there with command line (sudo rm, rm)
I've tried to move it to /dev/null, didn't work ;)

Answer (score 1):

- Open Terminal :

```
cd /Users/<user>/Library/CloudStorage/
sudo rm -rf 'GoogleDrive-email@domain.com' #this will gives some errors, most of the data would be deleted
mv 'GoogleDrive-email@domain.com' /tmp
```

- Open Finder

  - SHIFT+CMD+G
  - type /tmp
  - delete the folder from finder, MacOsX prompts for your password, and then successfully place the folder in the bin, that then can be emptied.

Note : Secure delete the file requires some additional steps to overwrite empty disk space (which can be difficult considering MacOSX and SSDs)

Comment: Moving the file to /tmp is the crucial thing. Even after removing the ACL permissions by `chmod -RN theFolderName` I was not successful in deleting the file. When moving the file to /tmp I was able to drop it with `sudo rm -rf theFolderName`.